# Map versus List

Tags: java, performance, dictionary

Input : Let's say I have an object as `Person`. It has 2 properties namely

- `ssnNo` - Social Security Number
- `name`.

In one hand I have a `List` of `Person` objects (with unique ssnNo) and in the other hand I have a `Map` containing Person's `ssnNo` as the key and Person's `name` as the value.

Output : I need Person names using its ssnNo.

Questions :

1. Which approach to follow out of the 2 I have mentioned above i.e. using list or map? (I think the obvious answer would be the map).
2. If it is the map, is it always recommended to use map whether the data-set is large or small? I mean are there any performance issues that come with the map.

Comment: Considering size of your collection as a contraint, i think google guava-libraries should be a good option.

Answer (score 3):

Map is the way to go. Maps perform very well, and their advantages over lists for lookups get bigger the bigger your data set gets.

Of course, there are some important performance considerations:

1. Make sure you have a good hashcode (and corresponding equals) implementation, so that you data will be evenly spread across the buckets of the Map.
2. Make sure you pre-size your Map when you allocate it (if at all possible). The map will automatically resize, but the resize operation essentially requires re-inserting each prior element into the new, bigger Map.

Comment: Thanks Rob for the clear explanation. (Sorry for the late reply..I was out)

Answer (score 0):

You're right, you should use a map in this case. There are no performance issues using map compared to lists, the performance is significantly better than that of a list when data is large. Map uses key's hashcodes to retrieve entries, in similar way as arrays use indexes to retrieve values, which gives good performance

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a situation appropriate for a `Map<Long, Person>` that maps a social security number to the relevant `Person`. You might want to consider removing the `ssnNo` field from `Person` so as to avoid any redundancies (since you would be storing those values as keys in your map).

In general, `Map`s and `List`s are very different structures, each suited for different circumstances. You would use the former whenever you want to maintain a set of key-value pairs that allows you to easily and quickly (i.e. in constant time) look up values based on the keys (this is what you want to do). You would use the latter when you simply want to store an ordered, linear collection of elements.

Answer (score 0):

I think it makes sense to have a `Person` object, but it also makes sense to use a `Map` over a `List`, since the look up time will be faster.  I would probably use a `Map` with `SSNs` as `keys` and `Person` objects as `values`:

```
  Map<SSN,Person> ssnToPersonMap;
```

Answer (score 0):

It's all pointers. It actually makes no sense to have a `Map<ssn,PersonName>` instead of a `Map<ssn,Person>`. The latter is the best choice most of the time.

Comment: Ok it might make sense in some situations, for example if you know you only need the names via the SSN.

Answer (score 0):

Using map especially one that implement using a hash table will be faster than the list since this will allow you to get the name in constant time O(1). However using the list you need to do a linear search or may be a binary search which is slower.